VSTO - C# detecting WPM inside Ms. Word
I recently use the step by step given from the Microsoft Website.
But unfortunately they didn't mention about the way how we could detect every buttons pressed from the user input while typing inside Ms. Word. Wouldn't it be possible anyway?
My pure objective is actually record the WPM (word perminute) as the user typed every character, every spaces, and so on.
But please not detecting when the mouse wanted to select the text, coz it's very different case.
anyone could give me some clue on this matter?

Word does not provide any API for that. But you can easily install a Windows hook using SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, ...) - in your hook proc, check for the messages being >= WM_KEYFIRST && <= WM_KEYLAST
